# How to Block X forwarded-for IP in nginx

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, deny

My website is running behind aws Load Balancer. Now if i try to deny any IP to access my website by using "deny 59.92.130.106" under location / nothing happened. That IP still getting 200 response.Anyone having idea why this happened and how can i block any ip in nginx running behind aws load balancer?
I used below entry but it is not working.

```
location / {
    deny 59.92.130.106;
}
```

Comment: Try the Real IP module. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html).

Comment: You could use AWS NACL for that.

Comment: @ClémentDuveau I don't have access of NACL. I have only server access that's why i have to block it at nginx level.

Comment: @RichardSmith Can you please describe how to use this Real IP module.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks with some tweaks now it's worked.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for help. I found solution for this issue. Maybe there is some bug in nginx due to which i found double IP in $http_x_forwarded_for but with the help of real_ip module now i able to block IP using $remote_addr header. By including below code in my vhost conf now i get client IP in $remote_addr header.

```
set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
        real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
        real_ip_recursive on;

set $allow true;
if ($remote_addr ~ "180.179.") {
     set $allow false;
}
if ($remote_addr ~ "199.47.") {
     set $allow false;
}
if ($allow = false) {
     return 403;
}
```

Comment: You should use [`deny`](https://nginx.org/r/deny) instead of `if`.

Answer (score 0):

If your load balancer is properly configured to support `X-Forwarder-For` HTTP header, you can use something like

```
map $http_x_forwarded_for $block {
    59.92.130.106         1;
    <another_blocked_ip>  1;
    ...
}
server {
    ...
    location / {
        if ($block) { return 403; }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

or if you want to allow access forsome IPs only

```
map $http_x_forwarded_for $block {
    59.92.130.106         '';
    <another_allowed_ip>  '';
    ...
    default               1;
}
```

Comment: I tried 

`map $http_x_forwarded_for $block {
    59.74.236.125         1;
}`
and
`location / {
  if ($block) { return 403; }
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }`
But still it's not working

Comment: @RahulAggarwal The AWS documentation [says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html) their load balancers should support `X-Forwarded-For` header. You can try to debug this defining [custom log format](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format) for your access log with `$http_x_forwarded_for` field included and check if this header is really set by load balancer. If it isn't, check your load balancer configuration. Didn't know how to help further.

Comment: I already configured custom log format with "$http_x_forwarded_for" and getting client IP but didn't know how to use `$http_x_forwarded_for` for blocking that same IP.

Comment: @RahulAggarwal Try `if ($block) { return 403; }` outside of the `location` block if you have several locations defined.

Comment: I also tried if ($block) { return 403; } outside of the location block but still it's not working

Comment: @RahulAggarwal Sorry, I don't know what to suggest further.